# Column is not type cast to object

Tags: python, pandas

This might be silly question but I want to still get a clear answer.
I have cleaned my data by treating missing values, changing factors to numeric data and then, saved my data to excel(.csv).

Later I read this data and found, categorical fields value are converted to float data type.

I used below code to convert it back to 'object' data type, however, it didn't work.

```
data.info()

categorical_feature = ['NAME_CONTRACT_TYPE', 'CODE_GENDER', 
    'FLAG_OWN_CAR', 'FLAG_OWN_REALTY', 'NAME_TYPE_SUITE', 
    'NAME_INCOME_TYPE', 'NAME_EDUCATION_TYPE', 'NAME_FAMILY_STATUS', 
    'NAME_HOUSING_TYPE', 'OCCUPATION_TYPE', 'WEEKDAY_APPR_PROCESS_START', 
    'ORGANIZATION_TYPE', 'FONDKAPREMONT_MODE', 'HOUSETYPE_MODE', 
    'WALLSMATERIAL_MODE', 'EMERGENCYSTATE_MODE']
data[categorical_features] = data[categorical_features].astype(object)


data.info()
```

---

Result :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 307511 entries, 0 to 307510
Columns: 122 entries, SK_ID_CURR to AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR
dtypes: float64(121), int64(1)
memory usage: 286.2 MB

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 307511 entries, 0 to 307510
Columns: 122 entries, SK_ID_CURR to AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR
dtypes: float64(121), int64(1)
memory usage: 286.2 MB
```

Comment: `feature` vs `features`? Do you have two different variables?

Comment: They were supposed to be same, though I didn't notice. Thank you. After correcting it worked out.

Comment: One more question: How does data Models (eg. CART, Logistic Regression, etc.) handles numerical and categorical features differently?